# C# How to block all sites except a particular site

Tags: c#, block, firewall, port80

Because of security issues, the company is developing programs to block specific sites on individual PCs for employees.

Find information and use "INetFwPolicy2" on C #.
There was a way to access the firewall and add port 80 to the outbound rules to block the Internet.

However, when you shut down port 80, all Internet access using http was blocked. 
By the way, when I shut down the port number 80, all Internet connections using the . were blocked.

The desired action is to block all Internet except for certain sites.

I need your help. Thanks

Comment: I think much better if your Company buy a Firewall itself.. than developing a new one.